# How to retrieve the name of a link?

Tags: php

I have a database and I generated a code that creates links depending on the name of the person in the database and I want the names to be 
"sent" in the next page ( link's page). So I used the method "get" to do that but it does not work and I don't know why.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_personne; ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo ("<a href=\"traitement.php?firsname=".$row["firsname"]."%"."&lastname=".$row["lastname"]."%".">".$row["firsname"]. " ".$row["lastname"]);
        echo "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo " 0 results";
}
```

The URL that is created is:  `traitement.php?prenom=paul%&nom=vincent%>paul%20vincent`

Problems: The URL does not match the name of the person displayed and the lastname is `"vincent%>paul"` meaning `lastname=$GET["lastname"]= "firstname%lastname<"` and there is no `$GET["firstname"]`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are the `%` symbols for?? Loose them and it will probably work.

Comment: `echo ("<a href=\"traitement.php?firsname=".$row["firsname"]."&lastname=".$row["lastname"].">".$row["firsname"]. " ".$row["lastname"]);`

Comment: You probably want to use http_build_query https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: @RiggsFolly My actual code was : echo ("<a href=\"traitement.php?prenom=".$row["prenom"]."&nom=".$row["nom"].">".$row["prenom"]. " ".$row["nom"]. "<br>"); But it does not work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this :

```
echo ('<a href="traitement.php?firstname='.$row["firstname"].'%&lastname='.$row["lastname"].'%">'.$row["firstname"]. " ".$row["lastname"]).'</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! :) You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You have to change this :

```
$row["firsname"]
```

to

```
$row["firstname"]
```